Why are colors so strangely showed?
When running the following code, I found the two colors red and blue very strangely displayed in plot; moreover, the legend has the colors mismatched:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

maxs = [35, 31, 35, 31, 34, 30, 31, 29, 30, 33]
clrs = ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))

sns.histplot(ax = ax, x = maxs, bins = "auto", discrete = True, shrink = 0.5,
             stat = "count", element = "bars", kde = False, hue = clrs) 

plt.show() 

I don't understand what kind of mistake(s) did I make? Could someone provide any help?


Does this answer your question? Change bar color according to hue name

Sorry, no. The answer provided uses a pd.dataframe. I then created a pd.dataframe with columns maxsand clrs but the problem remains.
I really don't understand why my code gives such a plotting result.

With hue=clrs, the names aren't interpreted as colors, just as unique strings. By coincident, the default colors happen to be blue and orange. (You would get the same colors if you'd set clrs = ['foo', 'bar', ...]). Adding a palette dictionary mapping the hue names to the corresponding color solves the issue. If all the hue names are valid color names, palette = {col: col for col in clrs} would work, the palette can be set manually.
As usually different hue values can occupy the same x-position, seaborn applies an alpha transparency. You can set the transparency to 1 if you are sure there won't be overlap.
bins is ignored when discrete=True.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

maxs = [35, 31, 35, 31, 34, 30, 31, 29, 30, 33]
clrs = ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))

sns.histplot(ax=ax, x=maxs, discrete=True, shrink=0.5,
             stat="count", element="bars", kde=False, hue=clrs,
             palette={'red': 'crimson', 'blue': 'dodgerblue'}, alpha=1)

plt.show()


